# javascript shows multiple hidden content using a checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When I click the check box, I want to see the two values (i am here, i am here too) but unfortunately I am able to see only (i am here!). I need to use queryselectorall but I havent managed yet. I have many divisions so I have just showed 2 division here and i need to change the id number always. Can i do it using same id or define a class? or i can always define a new id number. How can I show the values when I click checkbox?

```
-----------HTML-------------
<h3 align="center"> This JavaScript shows how to hide divisions </h3>

<div id="div1" style="display:none">
<table border=1 id="t1">
<tr>
<td>i am here!</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="div2" style="display:none">
<table border=1 id="t2">
<tr>
<td>i am here too!</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>


<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="c1" onclick="showMe('div1')">Show Hide Checkbox

</form>
-------- HTML END---------

--------------Javascript---------
     function showMe (box) {
    
    var chboxs = document.getElementsByName("c1");
    var vis = "none";
    for(var i=0;i<chboxs.length;i++) { 
        if(chboxs[i].checked){
         vis = "block";
            break;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById(box).style.display = vis;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show both divs, but you are only passing the id of one of the divs, `div1`.

One way would be to pass both ids to your Javascript function and change the display property for both divs.

Code snippet:

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="c1" onclick="showMe(['div1', 'div2'])">Show Hide Checkbox
```

**JavaScript**

```
function showMe(ids) {

    var chboxs = document.getElementsByName("c1");
    var vis = "none";
    for (var i = 0; i < chboxs.length; i++) {
        if (chboxs[i].checked) {
            vis = "block";
            break;
        }
    }
    ids.forEach(id => document.getElementById(id).style.display = vis);
}
```

The other option is to set a class (e.g. box) on both divs and pass that class name to your `showMe` function and iterate over all the elements with that class and set their display property.

Sample Code would be like below:

**HTML**

```
<h3 align="center"> This JavaScript shows how to hide divisions </h3>

<div id="div1" style="display:none" class="box">
    <table border=1 id="t1">
        <tr>
            <td>i am here!</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="div2" style="display:none" class="box">
    <table border=1 id="t2">
        <tr>
            <td>i am here too!</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="c1" onclick="showMe('box')">Show Hide Checkbox
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function showMe(cls) {

    var chboxs = document.getElementsByName("c1");
    var vis = "none";
    for (var i = 0; i < chboxs.length; i++) {
        if (chboxs[i].checked) {
            vis = "block";
            break;
        }
    }
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(cls);
    for (let e of elements) {
        e.style.display = vis;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you want execute the action in more than one element then you need to use class and not id.

Yoor code will work with this:

```
<div class="div" style="display:none">
<table border=1 id="t1">
<tr>
<td>i am here!</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div class="div" style="display:none">
<table border=1 id="t2">
<tr>
<td>i am here too!</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>


<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="c1">Show Hide Checkbox

</form>

<script>
  const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.div')
  
  document.querySelector('input[name="c1"]').onclick = (event) => {
    divs.forEach(div => {
      if (event.target.checked) {
        div.style.display = ''
      } else {
        div.style.display = 'none'
      }
    })
  }
</script>
```